# Need help with test class that mimics user input on visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, unit-test, code-coverage

We have a signature capture box on a visualforce page that was created long before I was around. I'm just changing it from being saved on the old Attachments object. For the life of me, I can't find the test class that was used when this was built, so I need to create a new one in order to deploy it to production. I struggle as it is with unit testing, and I have no idea how to go about it when javascript functions are involved. I don't know how to mimic the capturing of the signature on the test. I was hoping someone would lead me in the right direction. Thank you!

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Service_Call__c" extensions="SignaturepadSampleController" standardStylesheets="false" showheader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:includeScript value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"/>
    
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery_signaturepad, 'jquery.signaturepad.css')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery_signaturepad, 'jquery.signaturepad.min.js')}"/>
    
<script type='text/javascript' src='/canvas/sdk/js/30.0/publisher.js'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var SignPadTestApi;
        var SignFileName="AcceptanceSignature";
        var PenWidth = 2;
        var FormHeight=250;
        var FormWidth =280;
            
        $(function(){
             //canvas size
            $(".pad").attr({width:FormWidth-2, Height:FormHeight});
            //signature setting
            SignPadTestApi = $('.sigPad').signaturePad({drawOnly:true, penWidth:PenWidth, penColour:'#000000', lineTop:FormHeight*3/4}); 
            $('#sigArea').css('width', FormWidth + 1);  
            $('.sigPad').css('width', FormWidth);  
            $('.sigWrapper').css('height', FormHeight); 
        });
        
        function saveSign(){
            if(SignPadTestApi.getSignatureString().length!=2){
                var fileName = SignFileName;
                var signData = SignPadTestApi.getSignatureImage();
                saveSign2Obj(fileName, signData);
                //window.close();
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>        
        #sigArea{
            margin:0px auto;
        }
        .sigPad {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .sigWrapper {
            clear: both;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
    </style>
    
    <div id="sigArea">
        <h2 style="color:#0456A4">Work Acknowledgement</h2>
        <p><font size="2"><i>Service has been satisfactorily completed and customer has received instructions on use of equipment. In addition all combinations/keys have been turned over and tested by customer.</i></font></p>
        <form method="post" action="" class="sigPad">
            <p class="drawItDesc">Please Sign Below</p>
            <ul class="sigNav">
                <li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="sig sigWrapper">
                <canvas  class="pad"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output"/>
            </div>
            
        </form>
    </div>
    
    
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="saveSign2Obj" action="{!saveSIgn2Obj}" rerender="dummy" status="signatureStatus" oncomplete="oneAndDone();/*alert('signature successfully attached.');window.top.location='/{!obj.id}';*/">
            <apex:param name="fileName" assignTo="{!fileName}" value="" />
            <apex:param name="signData" assignTo="{!signData}" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
        
        <apex:actionStatus id="signatureStatus">
         <apex:facet name="start">    
          <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;padding-left:6px;">Saving Signature ...</span> 
          <img src="/img/loading.gif" alt=" " />      
         </apex:facet>                           
        </apex:actionStatus>    
    
    </apex:form>
<script> 
    Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe({name: "publisher.showPanel", 
         onData:function(e) { 
             Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name: 
                 "publisher.setValidForSubmit", payload:"true"}); 
    }}); 
    /*Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({
        name: "publisher.setValidForSubmit", 
        payload:"true"});*/
    Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe({
        name: "publisher.post",
        onData:function(e) {
            saveSign();
        }});
    var oneAndDone = function() {
        if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce != null) ) { 
             Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({
                name: "publisher.close",
                payload:{ refresh:"true"}
            });
        } else { 
             window.top.location='/{!obj.id}';
        }
        
        //
    }
</script>
<apex:outputpanel id="dummy"></apex:outputpanel>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class SignaturepadSampleController {
    public Sobject obj{set; get;}
    public String fileName{set;get;}
    public Transient String signData{set;get;}
    
    Public SignaturepadSampleController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
         this.obj = (Sobject)controller.getRecord();
    }
    
    Public PageReference saveSign2Obj() {
        
        //Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        //attachment.Name = fileName + '.png';  // filename
        //attachment.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(signData.remove('data:image/png;base64,'));  // data
        //attachment.ParentId = obj.Id;  // parent record Id
        //insert attachment;
        
        ContentVersion conVer = new ContentVersion();
        conVer.ContentLocation = 'S';
        conVer.PathOnClient = 'sigFile.png';
        conVer.Title = 'sigFile';
        conVer.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(signData.remove('data:image/png;base64,'));
        insert conVer;
        
        System.debug('ContentVersionId='+conVer.Id);
        
        // First get the Content Document Id from ContentVersion Object
        Id conDoc = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:conVer.Id].ContentDocumentId;
        
        System.debug('ContentDocumentId='+conDoc);
        
        //create ContentDocumentLink  record 
        ContentDocumentLink conDocLink = New ContentDocumentLink();
        conDocLink.LinkedEntityId = obj.Id; // Specify RECORD ID here i.e Any Object ID (Standard Object/Custom Object)
        conDocLink.ContentDocumentId = conDoc;  //ContentDocumentId Id from ContentVersion
        conDocLink.shareType = 'I';
        insert conDocLink;
        
        ContentDistribution conDis = new ContentDistribution();
        conDis.Name = 'sigFileDelivery';
        conDis.ContentVersionId = conVer.id;
        conDis.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit = FALSE;
        insert conDis;
        
        System.debug('ContentDistribution='+conDis.Id);
           
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can specify manually signData variable before running saveSign2Obj in unit tests

Comment: Did you try clicking "run all tests" and check in dev console which class is doing code coverage?